# Link_to Image_tag onclick misfiring (Rails + JS)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I noticed this weird behavior when I do the following:

```
 <%= link_to(image_tag('some_image', class:"some_class", onclick:"someFunction(event)"),some_path) %>
```

later calling `event.target;` returns *`undefined`*. I investigated this and it is because the `event` is the `image_tag` instead of the `link_to`.

so I guess **my question is: why does this happen and how do I prevent it?**

I ended up splitting the link and the image and putting the `onclick` on the `link_to` (the image is obviously not clickable and there's this ugly button under it, just curious if there is a way around this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events traverse up the dom tree, aka bubble up. `target` returns the element where the click happened. `currentTarget` returns the element where handler function is attached.

```html
<a onclick="clickable(event)" href="#">
  <img src="/assets/sample.jpg">        <!-- if you click `img` -->
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function clickable(event){
    console.log(event.target)           <!-- this will return `img` -->
    console.log(event.currentTarget)    <!-- this will return `a` -->
  }
</script>
```

```html
<a onclick="clickable(event)" href="#"> <!-- if you click `a` -->
  <img src="/assets/sample.jpg">     
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function clickable(event){
    console.log(event.target)           <!-- this will return `a` -->
    console.log(event.currentTarget)    <!-- this will return `a` -->
  }
</script>
```

If you need to get the link, make sure `onclick` is on the link and then call `currentTarget`.

Comment: you did it again! you've been saving my behind all week!

Answer (score 0):

This will add link to image and `event.target` will be image.

```
<%= link_to image_tag('some_image', class:"some_class"), some_path, onclick: "someFunction(event)" %>
```

Comment: this is what i currently had and it didn't work, i tried playing around with the () like you did here and it still didn't work. Thank you though!